# Spring Boot JPA Specification - Can I use fields not present on the entity?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm building Specifications in a class that look like this:

```
public static Specification<Consultant> likeFirstName(String query) {
    return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> 
    criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(Consultant_.firstName), "%" + query + "%");
}
```

I have additional fields in my datasource that I'd like to build specifications for. These fields currently don't exist on my entity. I've been scouring the internet for a resource that would let me know if I could provide something like a generic string as a field name and it could be used to build a valid Specification. Something like:

```
public static Specification<Consultant> likeDisplayName(String query) {
    return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
    criteriaBuilder.like(root.<String>get("blark"), "%" + query + "%");
}
```

This particular attempt results in an IllegalArgumentException

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [blark] on this ManagedType [Consultant]
```

In this case "blark" is a field in my database that is not mapped to my entity, but I want to build a spec that uses this field. Is this possible without adding the field to my entity?

Comment: The only way that Spring is recognize a DB object is through a persistence layer which make the connection between your entities and the DB ones. I've never heard of accessing DB without a persistence object, i.e. an entity. BTW, why don't you want to add some more fields to your entity?